# How do I round a float upwards to the nearest int in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

In C#, how do I round a float upwards to the nearest int?

I see Math.Ceiling and Math.Round, but these returns a decimal.  Do I use one of these then cast to an Int?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net for a full roundup.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you want to round to the **nearest** int:

```
int rounded = (int)Math.Round(precise, 0);
```

You can also use:

```
int rounded = Convert.ToInt32(precise);
```

Which will use `Math.Round(x, 0);` to round and cast for you. It looks neater but is slightly less clear IMO.

---

If you want to round **up**:

```
int roundedUp = (int)Math.Ceiling(precise);
```

Comment: There is ambiguity in the question.  The title suggests he wants to round up, while he states he wants the nearest int.  These are 2 different things.

Comment: He wanted to round up. Wouldn't that be (int)Math.Ceiling(precise) ?

Comment: @configurator, yea, that is what I'm thinking.

Comment: I'd also like to note that Math.Round uses banker's rounding. That is, a number with a non-integer part of exactly .5 would be rounded to the nearest even number. This is useful when doing aggregate sums of rounded numbers, but is usually unexpected - Math.Round(3.5) = 4, Math.Round(6.5) = 6.

Comment: Isn't there a risk of floating-point inaccuracies causing trouble here?
If `Math.Round(precise, 0)` yields a floating-point value which is smaller than the actual value by any non-zero amount, `(int)Math.Round(precise, 0)` would equal `(int)precise`, right?
I imagine a simpler and safer solution would be to simply use `int rounded = (int)(precise+.5f);`.

Comment: Round takes double arguments. The poster asked for float.

Comment: @jeancallisti It should go without saying that the float can be cast to a double

Answer (score 18):

Off the top of my head:

```
float fl = 0.678;
int rounded_f = (int)(fl+0.5f);
```

Comment: Care to explain that last f (0.5f)?

Comment: As a float cast to an int will get rounded down the +0.5 ensures the cast rounds to the nearest int. However, this only works for positive floats.

Answer (score 3):

(int)Math.Round(myNumber, 0)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to just add `0.5f` to it and then cast this to an int.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I use one of these then cast to an Int?

Yes. There is no problem doing that. Decimals and doubles can represent integers exactly, so there will be no representation error. (You won't get a case, for instance, where Round returns 4.999... instead of 5.)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to an int provided you are sure it's in the range for an int (Int32.MinValue to Int32.MaxValue).