# Increasing the value by 1 if it has decimal place?

Tags: c#, rounding

My scenario is that if

```
47/15= 3.13333
```

i want to convert it into 4, if the result has decimal i want to increase the result by 1, right now i am doing this like

```
        float res = ((float)(62-15) / 15);
        if (res.ToString().Contains("."))
        {
             string digit=res.ToString().Substring(0, res.ToString().IndexOf('.'));
             int incrementDigit=Convert.ToInt16(k) + 1;


        }
```

I want to know is there any shortcut way or built in function in c# so that i can do this fast without implementing string functions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Math.Ceiling?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zx4t0t48.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904910/how-do-i-round-a-float-up-to-the-nearest-int-in-c

Comment: Do you mean something like the `System.Math.Ceiling` which rounds up? (Subquestion: if your number is negative `-3.13333` should that still "add" one and make -4 or _really_ add and make it -3?)

Comment: Did you check [`Math.Ceiling`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832978/how-to-convert-math-ceiling-result-to-int) ?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair No, My number will number will never have negative value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean you want to perform integer division, but always rounding up? I suspect you want:

```
public static int DivideByFifteenRoundingUp(int value) {
    return (value + 14) / 15;
}
```

This avoids using floating point arithmetic at all - it just allows any value which isn't an exact multiple of 15 to be rounded up, due to the way that integer arithmetic truncates towards zero.

Note that this does *not* work for negative input - for example, if you passed in -15 this would return 0. you could fix this with:

```
public static int DivideByFifteenRoundingUp(int value) {
    return value < 0 ? value / 15 : (value + 14) / 15;
}
```

Comment: Can I up vote this answer twice? Very nice solution for rounding up integers.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Math.Ceiling` Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/1cz5da1c.aspx):

> Returns the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to
>   the specified decimal number.

Comment: There's no need to do this though - there are easy ways of always rounding up, without going to floating point at all.

Comment: You are right, but assuming he has result 3.13333, he have floating point. Your code is faster but much difficult to understand for a beginner.

Comment: But if you take a step back, he doesn't have that result - he just wants integer division, rounding up. Note that in your version you then need to cast back to `int` *and* it wil give "interesting" results for very large numbers, where `float`'s granularity is larger than an integer.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`Math.Ceiling()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx).

Convert the value you have to a Decimal or Double and the result of that method is what you need. Like:

```
double number = ((double)(62-15) / (double)15);
double result = Math.Ceiling(number);
```

Note the fact that I cast 15 to a double, so I avoid integer division. That is most likely not what you want here.

Comment: this is what i need "always round off +1 irrespective of any decimal value" Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing what you ask is to add 0.5 to every number, then floor it (truncate the decimal places).  I'm afraid I don't have access to a C# compiler right now to confirm the exact function calls!

NB: But as others have confirmed, I would think the Math.Ceiling function best communicates to others what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
float res = ((float)(62-15) / 15);

int incrementDigit = (int)Math.Ceiling(res);
```

or

```
int incrementDigit  = (int)(res  + 0.5f);
```