# Object not instantiating, when comparing position in Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script attached to the Main Camera. I want to instantiate an object whenever the camera is at a specific position in the y axis. But the object doesn't instantiate. Here's the script.

```
public GameObject obj;

private void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y % 2 == 0) {

    Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), Quaternion.identity);

   }

}
```

Is it something to do with the modulus function?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not instantiating because `if (transform.position.y % 2 == 0) {` is not `true`. The reason `if (transform.position.y % 2 == 0)` is not evaluating to true is because `transform.position.y` is a `float`. When you divide that `float` by 2, the remainder will likely not be a `0`.

[Round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904910/how-do-i-round-a-float-up-to-the-nearest-int-in-c) that `float` to the nearest `int` before you comparing it to `0`.This can be done with `Convert.ToInt32` or `Math.Round`. There are other ways to do this too.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(transform.position.y) % 2 == 0)
{
    //Instantiate
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that when I manually changed the camera position to 2 and it instantiated the object fine. Rounding off the number works. Thank You.