# How to round to a specific decimal accuracy?

Tags: c#, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I have  a  value `var i = 0.69999980926513672`. I need to round this value to `0.7` is there  a built-in method that will do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) method.

```
//first param is number to round
//second param is the accuracy to use in the rounding (number of decimal places)
Math.Round(i, 2)
```

Answer (score 13):

Use one of:

```
System.Math.Round (i, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
System.Math.Round (i, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The difference is how it handles numbers that are equidistant to the rounding point (e.g., 0.65 in your case could either go to 0.7 or 0.6).

Here is a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252) I gave to another question which holds much more information.

Comment: Leveraging your rich portfolio of answers +1

Comment: As my wife says when I'm in full flight, conversationally speaking, the less people are forced to listen to me, the happier they seem to become :-) So it's probably best to keep the answers short and reference my more voluminous essays with links.

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round(0.69999980926513672d, 1));
```

-- edit

wow, you blink and there are 5 other answers!

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked "math" questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) method:

```
double i = 0.69999980926513672;
double result = Math.Round(i, 2);
```