# roundoff double values in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I have a matrix.I found the 10th power of matrix using Java.After finding the 10th power,I need to round off the double values to 3 decimal places.Please help me to round off the double values in the  matrix to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really round `double` values to decimal places since `double` is a binary format, not decimal, and will internally be rounded to binary fractions.

Instead, you should do the rounding when you format the output. This can be done in Java in a number of ways:

```
String.format("%.2f", 1.2399) // returns "1.24"
new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(1.2)// returns "1.20"
new DecimalFormat("0.##").format(1.2)// returns "1.2"
```

Read [the Floating-Point](http://floating-point-gui.de/) guide for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you really want a double with the value (close to) rounded you could do something like:

```
val = Math.round(val * 1000) / 1000.0;
```

where val is the number you want rounded.
I used 1000 for 3 decimal places; use 10^n for n decimal places. 
Also notice that after '/' I used the double literal '1000.0' (with the '.0' after '1000') to ensure the result is a double (since Math.round rounds off to a long value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat class. Something like this

```
double unformated = 0.34556 // your double;
double formated = new DecimalFormat("0.###").format((double)unformated);
```

Comment: That won't compile, since format() returns a String.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [java.math.BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to round:

```
BigDecimal initialValue = new BigDecimal(65.432105);
double rounded = initialValue.setScale(3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
System.out.println("rounded = " + rounded ); // outputs 65.432
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following obsurce piece of code. This only works for |values| < Long.Max_VALUE/1000

```
public static double round3(double d) {
  return ((double) (long) ((d < 0 ? d - 0.5 : d + 0.5) * 1000))/1000;
}
```