# Round to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I have:

```
mkm=((((amountdrug/fluidvol)*1000)/60)*infrate)/ptwt;
```

in my Java code. The code works fine but returns to several decimal places. How do I limit it to just 2 or 3?

Comment: Not the same. The linked dupe candidate discusses how to print a rounded number, not how to actually round the value stored in the variable.

Answer (score 90):

Don't use doubles.  You can lose some precision.  Here's a general purpose function.

```
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}
```

You can call it with

```
round(yourNumber, 3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

"precision" being the number of decimal points you desire.

Comment: Thanks bluedevil for taking the time to reply. I have tried your suggestion and get errors saying 'BigDecimal cannot be resolved to a type'. I'm afraid I'm new to this and need the idiots guide!

Comment: import java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 10):

Just use Math.round()

```
double mkm = ((((amountdrug/fluidvol)*1000f)/60f)*infrate)/ptwt;

mkm= (double)(Math.round(mkm*100))/100;
```

Comment: math.round won't work here as you arent getting 2 decimal places as per question

Answer (score 8):

```
double formattedNumber = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(unformattedNumber));
```

worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 1000, round, and divide back by 1000.

For basic Java:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn for the reply. In the distant past when I used to program in basic I would use the way you suggested (although it was int(x) not round). I cannot figure out how to do this in android java though.

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("12345.0789");
 
a = a.divide(new BigDecimal("1"), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 

//Also check other rounding modes
 
System.out.println("a >> "+a.toPlainString()); //Returns 12345.08`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
float number mkm = (((((amountdrug/fluidvol)*1000f)/60f)*infrate)/ptwt)*1000f;
int newNum = (int) mkm;
mkm = newNum/1000f; // Will return 3 decimal places
```

Comment: Hi travega, I appriciate you taking the time to help me with this. 
I have copied and pasted the code you supplied, but am getting the error - 'syntax error, insert";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement'. I have checked the three ';' in the above code are in place.

Answer (score -2):

Create a class called Round and try using the method round as **Round.round(targetValue, roundToDecimalPlaces)** in your code

```
public class Round {

        public static float round(float targetValue, int roundToDecimalPlaces ){

            int valueInTwoDecimalPlaces = (int) (targetValue * Math.pow(10, roundToDecimalPlaces));

            return (float) (valueInTwoDecimalPlaces / Math.pow(10, roundToDecimalPlaces));
        }

    }
```