# How can i format decimal numbers upto two decimal points in java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596023/round-to-2-decimal-places)

Suppose in a variable i have a decimal number like 3.1426384473 but i want 3.14. now how i can format decimal numbers up to two decimals points like in above example.

Comment: You can do that with a [DecimalFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

double pi=3.1426384473;

System.out.printf("%.2f",pi);

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.format(3.1426384473);
```

Or if u just wanna print then u can use this also...

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",d); //d is your number
```

Comment: there are so many other methods to do that I think Google is just great....isn't it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```