# Print float with two decimals unless number is a mathematical integer

Tags: java, kotlin

Is there a simple way of printing a floating value as a string with decimals if the value has decimals, other wise print it like an int without decimals?

```
12.5 would print 12.50
15.0 would print 15
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I can think of ways which includes parse floats to strings to ints but it doesn't seem optimal.

EDIT: This answer does **not** do what I want: [Show decimal of a double only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826439/show-decimal-of-a-double-only-when-needed)

This answers only shows one decimal if the value only has one decimal. What I need is two decimals, or nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show decimal of a double only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826439/show-decimal-of-a-double-only-when-needed)

Comment: The way I know (the old way) was using DecimalFormat. I believe there's a newer way to do it using printf

Comment: @Milgo, I was a little quick to respond. No, its close to what I need. If the value has one decimal it should display two decimals. This way shows only one.

Comment: Then you should go for [Java Currency Number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.format()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html), and strip off the decimal if it's `.00` with [`removeSuffix()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-suffix.html):

```kotlin
fun Double.toMyFormat(): String =
    String.format("%.2f", this).removeSuffix(".00")

fun main() {
    println(12.5.toMyFormat())
    println(15.0.toMyFormat())
}
```

Prints:

```
12.50
15
```

This also works with rounded numbers such as `12.999` etc.

Comment: @Reporter yes they are.

Comment: Nice one liner!