# Rounding up to 2 decimal place

Tags: java, rounding

I have this code below, my desired answer is 37.58 and not 37.56 or 37.60 after inputting 37576

```
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(num);
BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(100);

BigDecimal res = n.divide(t);
BigDecimal b =res.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
DecimalFormat forma = new DecimalFormat("K0.00");
String bigf = forma.format(b);



txtnewk.setText(" " + bigf);
```

what changes do I have to make?

Comment: i don't understand what your actual result is ?

Comment: Not about `android` at all

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596023/round-to-2-decimal-places/

Comment: I am building a denomination converter whose conversion standard is 1000-1. so in a case where I want to convert 37576 I want my answer to be 37.58

Answer (score 3):

With the following code:

```
String num = "37576";
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(num);
BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(1000);
BigDecimal res = n.divide(t);
BigDecimal b = res.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

b is 37.58 as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point) for rounding numbers:

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong version of divide (if you are rounding it immediately). Value of setScale is wrong. You should have:

```
BigDecimal res = n.divide(t, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `double` you can do

```
long l = 37576; // or Long.parseLong(text);
double v = Math.round(l / 10.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
37.58
```

The first rounded `/ 10.0` says you want to drop the lowest digit by rounding and the `/ 100.0` says you want to shift the decimal place by two digits.