# Truncation or DecimalFormat in Java

Tags: java, jtextfield, truncation

I have this:

```
if (inKm) 
{
    text = String.valueOf(MetricConverter.milesToKilometers(Double.valueOf(text)));

}
```

This yields a result into a JTextField that is a bit too long for my liking. How do I truncate or use decimalformat on the resulting value? When I used decimalformat within this expression it just bugged out the program.

Comment: You may want to look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3596122/859485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use this since it's so similar to `printf()`

```
double doubleValue = 123.4567895;
String.format("%.2f", doubleValue); // returns "123.46"
```

Edit: This does not truncate, but rounds half-up.

More info on how to use the `String.format()`, and `java.util.Formatter`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Ah, okay. I want to get it to one decimal place.

Comment: That's not what I mean. This also bugs out the program

Comment: @RandyB. Are you doing `text = String.format("%.1f", MetricConverter.milesToKilometers(Double.valueOf(text)));`? or what kind of error are you getting? `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: when I do that, it does cut off, but it messes up the calculation in some way. I cant figure out why just yet