# Android: Wrong calculation in type double

Tags: types, double

Help please. I have a problem with the wrong calculations when using like double. For example, we use a code below:

```
double a = 2.01;
double b = 1.01;
double c = 100*(a - (int)a);
double d = 100*(b-(int)b);
```

In my log I see the following: c = 1.0000001 and d = 0.99999987. How to make so that calculations were more exact result, namely, 0.01? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Check this other question and this particular answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3596122/2206688

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round(num)` instead of int casting.

Comment: That will not fix the underlying problem. Furthermore, if `a` i `2.51`, this will yield a negative number instead of a positive one, which doesn't seem to be be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your maths with [BigDecimal](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that doubles are binary-based and have limited precision. They can not exactly represent `2.01` or `1.01` (or [almost all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) real numbers). This does not mean they're useless, often we don't care about small differences like this. If you do, you will have to use something else (like fixed point or BigDecimal)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a computer doesn't think or store numbers like us. There are several ways of storing and accessing floating point numbers in a computer - its called numerical analysis; basically how floating point numbers are approximated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis