# Wrong double calculation

Tags: java, double

some calculations with doubles return the wrong result.

E.g.

```
System.out.println(""+(0.05+0.01));
```

output

```
0.060000000000000005
```

What can I do to correct this error?

Comment: Learn to use the `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: There's no error. Doubles have finite precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubles are *not* made for precise calculations (see [Round to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596023/round-to-2-decimal-places/3596122#3596122)) - for precise calculations, use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: BigDecimal only has a precision advantage for numbers with terminating decimal expansions. It is no better at representing one third than double.