# Format double to 2 decimal places with leading 0s

Tags: java, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I am trying to format a double to 2 decimal places with leading zeros and there's no luck.
Here is my code:

```
Double price = 32.0;
DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Double price2 = Double.parseDouble(decim.format(price));
```

And I want output to be `32.00` instead I get `32.0`
Any solutions??

Comment: Since it looks like you're dealing with currency here, consider using `BigDecimal` to represent money. Using floating-point numbers can lead to rounding problems.

Comment: I'm sure there are a million SO threads on currency.  I prefer integers to BigDecimal and then I deal in terms of pennies.  Of course, that's neither here nor there...

Comment: your code isn't quite right (for example you never show how you are getting the output).  Could you change your program to a complete working one (with a class and a main method) and tell us the expected output?

Comment: new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(double-value);

Answer (score 61, accepted):

OP wants leading zeroes.  If that's the case, then as per Tofubeer:

```
    DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

---

Edit:

Remember, we're talking about formatting numbers here, not the internal representation of the numbers.

```
    Double price = 32.0;
    DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Double price2 = Double.parseDouble(decim.format(price));
    System.out.println(price2);
```

will print `price2` using the *default* format.  If you want to print the formatted representation, print using the format:

```
    String s = decim.format(price);
    System.out.println("s is '"+s+"'");
```

In this light, I don't think your `parseDouble()` is doing what you want, nor can it.

Comment: also tried this and still not working

Comment: It works for me.  Post some example data and the results produced by the code above.

Comment: Hey thanks. the above code works perfect for me. I realized I was making a mistake by converting it to double again when actually I jus had t print it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
 DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Comment: tried this and its not working..

Comment: This is the answer if your already working in doubles. I was sent on a wild goose chase with an idea to convert it to a BigDecimal but this is simple and works great.

Comment: it doesn´t work :(