# Rounding double value into two significant digits in java

Tags: java, android, rounding, number-formatting

I want to get a function which rounds the double value into two significant digits
now i m using the below function

```
private static DecimalFormatSymbols DFS;
private static DecimalFormat myFormatter;
public static String DoubleToFormatedString(double value) {
    DFS = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    DFS.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("############.##");
    myFormatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(DFS);
    return myFormatter.format(value);
}
```

but with this function eg: i m getting a rounded number 2.6, i need to get this like 2.60.
 '0'should come to the right of 1 significant num. what change should make? or any other way plz help me

Comment: From the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) '0': Digit, '#': Digit, zero shows as absent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your formatter as below

```
myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

For further details you can refer to this SO question : [Format double to 2 decimal places with leading 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973763/format-double-to-2-decimal-places-with-leading-0s)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes just use

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

instead of

```
 DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("############.##");
```