# Formatting double to 2 decimals doesn't work

Tags: java, double, rounding

I want to round this double:

```
3.499999999999999
```

to:

```
3.50
```

And I already used these two methods:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double result = Double.valueOf(df.format(input));
        System.out.println(answer);
```

and

```
public double round(double input)
    {
        int decimalPlace = 2;
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(input);
        bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);

        return (bd.doubleValue());
    }
```

But It keeps printing:

```
3.5
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Because I really think that this should work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Given that 3.5 == 3.50 maybe your question should be about formatting and not rounding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first solution is really, really close.  Just do this:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println(df.format(input));
```

The reason your version doesn't work is that you're taking the `input` double, formatting it as a `String` with 2dp, but then converting it back to a `double`.  `System.out.println` is then printing the `double` as it always would, with no special decimal-place rules.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the printf formatting which may be simpler.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", 3.5);
```

prints

```
3.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try replacing the `0`'s with `#`'s?

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(df.format(input));

According to [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) the `#` will be resolved to 0 if the digit is absent

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly the wrong way round for what the questioner wants.  "#.##" will print "3.5", "0.00" will print "3.50".  (Just tested it to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Precision class of apache commons-math

```
double result = Precision.round(3.499999999999999, 2);
```