# how to convert double to 2 number after the dot?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

how to convert double to 2 number after the dot ?

for example:

```
double x=123.45678;
```

i need that `x=123.45` (in java for android)

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to convert `x` from `double` to different type (such as `String` with only two digits after the dots printed in it)? Or do you want to keep the double but truncate that part?

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
x = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: i used this method but if the number has example like 6.50 it shows 6.5. how i can add the zero?

Comment: @GeorgePanayi, you mean string formatting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal. First check whether `Math.abs(x) % 1.0 < 0.005;`. If it is whole, format `x` as whole number, and if fractional, then use `new DecimalFormat("###########0.00").format(x);`.

Comment: This does not do what OP asked for. Test the code with OPs examples. It will truncate the decimals, since this is an integer division in floating point context.

Answer (score 19):

try this code

```
double x=123.45678;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String dx=df.format(x);
x=Double.valueOf(dx);
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123,46"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)

Comment: I uses it but it shows value in this form "7016,01" instead of "7016.01". It show a qoma instead of dot.

Comment: replace , by . in dx: 
             x=Double.valueOf(dx.replace(',', '.'));

Comment: @sajid45, how can it be? Does it depend on regional settings?

Answer (score 14):

use this,

```
  NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
 x=formatter.format(x);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class for correct formatting of numbers.

Specifically in your case you can do the following. Although this is not ver L10N friendly.

```
mNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
mNumberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
mNumberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Comment: using String that working.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to format a double is with the NumberFormat class:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

You'll be doing something like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(); // get instance
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // set decimal places
String s = nf.format(x);
```

You can also cast it back to a double.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get two digits correctly rounded, I would go with BigDecimals:

```
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(x);
        System.out.println(bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());
```