# Show only two digit after decimal

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

How to get the double value that is only two digit after decimal point.

for example

if

```
i=348842.
double i2=i/60000;
tv.setText(String.valueOf(i2));
```

this code generating `5.81403333`.

But I want only `5.81`.

So what shoud I do?

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415733/how-to-convert-double-to-2-number-after-the-dot This question is asking about formatting; that question is asking about changing the value in a `double`.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats
>   decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it
>   possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support
>   for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits. It also supports different
>   kinds of numbers, including integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4), percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be localized.

*Code snippet* -

```
double i2=i/60000;
tv.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(i2));
```

*Output* -

> 5.81

Comment: You do not need toString(), format already returns  a String. Please also visit http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: what if i want in double format?

Comment: Its double value which can be formated desired string representation by using `DecimalFormat`. Well I did not undeerstand your question 100%.

Comment: This is working file. (3.5).ToString("0.00")  will show you [3.50].

Comment: It worked most of as I desired. but in my case, I needed single digit after decimal place. Thus used like - new DecimalFormat("##.#"), But, it didn't work for the cases with 0 after decimal like 35.0 as its showing it **35**. But, I need something like **35.0**

Comment: String amt = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(448.4); -> its gives 448.4 only
String amt = new DecimalFormat("##.00").format(448.4); -> Its gives 448.40

Comment: thumbs up for the info that it can be localized

Answer (score 153):

How about `String.format("%.2f", i2)`?

Comment: Much less typing than the decimal format, lmao. Thanks.

Comment: This might format the string with a comma, depending on the locale, e.g. result = 5,32 instead of 5.32.

Comment: I used  `String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", i2)`

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 30):

Here i will demonstrate you that how to make your decimal number short. Here i am going to make it short upto 4 value after decimal.

```
  double value = 12.3457652133
  value =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(value));
```

Comment: for set text to Textview  Eg:   double value = 12.3457652133
   textview.setText( new 
 DecimalFormat("##.##").format(Double.parseDouble(value)));

Comment: This have a limitation, you should be sure that the local used by `DecimalFormat` is returning decimal value with a dot not comma, otherwise the `parseDouble` will throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Working good without error

Answer (score 17):

Many other answers only do formatting. This approach will return **value** instead of only print format.

```
double number1 = 10.123456;
double number2 = (int)(Math.round(number1 * 100))/100.0;
System.out.println(number2);
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you.

Comment: worked for me too

Answer (score 9):

I think the best and simplest solution is (KISS):

```
double i = 348842;
double i2 = i/60000;
float k = (float) Math.round(i2 * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: I believe he's interested how to *display* only 2 significant digits. Also, because of the way floating point works, your solution will not result exactly in `5.81`, but something like `5.81000000001` or the like.

Comment: I think it's impossible! Because Math.round - returns integer and we cast it to float value. How is float value (581.0) after dividing by 100 can be something like 5.81000000001? Do you have test case that describe your opinion?

Comment: May be this is a simple code for a programmer, It helped me in the critical situation. Thanks buddy...1 upvote for u

Comment: This method will be very prone to floating point math errors as @Petriborg pointed out

Answer (score 3):

```
i=348842.
double i2=i/60000;
DecimalFormat dtime = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
i2= Double.valueOf(dtime.format(time));
v.setText(String.valueOf(i2));
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing that should pop in a developer head while formatting a number into char sequence should be care of such details like do it will be possible to reverse the operation.

And other aspect is providing proper result. So you want to  truncate the number or round it.

So before you start you should ask your self, am i interested on the value or not.

To achieve your goal you have multiple options but most of them refer to [Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Format.html) and [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), but i just suggest to look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java).

Comment: Reverse the operation? Quiet the opposite: formatting a number as a string should be done for system output only and reversing it should not be needed in a well designed system.