# round up to 2 decimal places in java?

Tags: java

I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions but none seems to be working for me. i am using `math.round()` to round off.
this is the code:

```
class round{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    double a = 123.13698;
    double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100;

    System.out.println(roundOff);
}
}
```

the output i get is: `123` but i want it to be `123.14`. i read that adding `*100/100` will help but as you can see i didn't manage to get it to work.

it is absolutely essential for both input and output to be a double.

it would be great great help if you change the line 4 of the code above and post it.

Comment: With the *100/100 technique used above I believe you want to truncate, not round.  `Math.floor(a*100) / 100d)`  Think about what the math is doing:  123.1299 * 100 = 12312.99.  Floor() = 12312.0 then /100 = 123.12

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10959430/621951 the best solution.It works.

Comment: Try Math.round(a * 100) / 100d;

Comment: Your problem is that you're doing integer division in a floating point context. This means that whenever you divide a float or double with an integer, they will be truncated. Some IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ) will warn you about this.

Answer (score 571, accepted):

**Well this one works...**

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Output is

```
123.14
```

Or as @Rufein said

```
 double roundOff = (double) Math.round(a * 100) / 100;
```

this will do it for you as well.

Comment: Could this be tweaked to round up to 3 or 5 decimal places ?

Comment: It also works `double roundOff = (double) Math.round(a * 100) / 100;`

Comment: +1 or `double roundOff = Math.round(a * 100) / 100.0;`

Comment: @SiB floor(x + 0.5) is different to round(x) for just *one* value,  the value immediately less than 0.5. This is because `0.49999999999999994 + 0.5` is `1.0` when it should be rounded down to `0.0`

Comment: -1 multiplying by 100 will not work for too large numbers, as they will go out of range and will begin from lower limit. Answer by @amitchhajer is correct in this matter

Comment: @Martin Asenov you are correct. but the range for double in java is   2^-1074 <= x <= (2-2^-52)·2^1023 // where x is the double. Don't you think if your numbers are going out of range for doubles than the whole approach needs to be revisited?

Comment: well yes, because it actually happened to me :)

Comment: Still wondering why no one mentioned  new BigDecimal(123.13698).round(new MathContext(5)).doubleValue()

Comment: @SiB double roundOff = Math.round(a * 100.0) / 100.0 works fine. But, double roundOff = Math.round(a * 1.0) / 1.0 doesn't work. Why so?

Comment: it return zero for some values dont know why !!

Comment: @Muhammad Gelbana - Number of zeroes increases the position. Eg - (1000.0) / 1000.0 for 3 decimal round off.

Comment: ( Math.round(395.0349999999 * 100 ) / 100.0. ) will become 395.03. I can see why as 395034 is nearest long that is then divided by 100. However I think generally people would expect the result as 395.04.

Comment: It works, but it looks sooooo ugly! I would expect something like `round(double, int=0)` for this purpose, it would be so much more readable...

Comment: @VishalSaxena if people expect the result to be 395.04 then they are simply wrong. 395.0349999999 is closer to 395.03, therefore 395.03 is the correct answer.

Comment: How about `double roundOff = Math.rint(a * 100) / 100;`

Comment: For anybody who is looking for a generalized form which rounds to a specified number of decimals `Math.round(395.03423578234 * Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals) ) / Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals)`. But please consider @Martin Asenov comment before considering this approach

Comment: @VishalSaxena Your rounding is off. You only look at the decimal number before the the one you want to round off. For example 94.994999999 is still 94.99 if you round off 2 decimal numbers, because the next one is a 00.004

Comment: @VishalSaxena Your logic would be correct if it was 395.0369999999 then it would be 395.04 because the third decimal is 0.006 and in your example the third decimal is 0.004 which is closer to 0 and the other is closer to 1. 0.5 is tricky but usually rounded up higher.

Comment: As @VishalSaxena said people would expect 395.0349999999 to become 395.04. This is because of the assumption that some previous division produced the above number instead of 395.035 which should be rounded to 395.04.

Answer (score 117):

```
     double d = 2.34568;
     DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
     System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

Comment: it says `DecimalFormat cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: did you import java.text.DecimalFormat; ?

Comment: that works only if double number is not lesser then 1 and greater then -1 - when that happens it doesnt show 0.

Comment: double doubleValue = 245;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
  System.out.println("value: " + Float.valueOf(df.format(doubleValue))); prints 245.0 not 245.00

Comment: Decimal Format does not round off the last decimal value for any of its functions. The margin for the round off for all the functions is >5 but its supposed to be >4. Eg - 1.235 should round off to 1.24 but the DF formatting rounds it to 1.23 which is wrong. 
But Math.round is accurate.

Comment: No way it wont work. Question is for round off the value. Not only Formatting. Anyway if you want to use DecimalFormattter then you have to set RoundingMode to up or down. decimalFormatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP); decimalFormatrer.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

Comment: But what if you want to use the number afterwards? Parse it again? that's no viable option

Comment: @Ronnie it does round on Java 12.0.2.

Comment: This is not rounding, for example 0.00005 with #.#### mask will be formatted just to zero

Comment: It should be `DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");` for some case like as `0.234`

Comment: It's important to note the format that format function uses the Locale.getDefault() instance, so if you are planning a developer for different timezones you must be aware of every Regional format could be different.

Comment: @HuyNguyen you are right but it will not work properly.. i.e. i have value around 32.. and this will showing 3.2..

Comment: This will give you a String. Also messed with my float point changing it to a coma ( my locale but I don't want it )

Answer (score 81):

```
String roundOffTo2DecPlaces(float val)
{
    return String.format("%.2f", val);
}
```

Comment: @CarlosA.Junior do you say using above way would not give consistent results ?

Comment: Yes @Arun. Using String.format, I can format the same way my country uses to round taxes' decimal places.

Answer (score 60):

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("123.13698");
BigDecimal roundOff = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(roundOff);
```

Comment: `BigDecimal.ROUND*` is deprecated since [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Yep, for Java 9+, use `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` to replicate this solution

Answer (score 14):

Go back to your code, and replace `100` by `100.00` and let me know if it works.
However, if you want to be formal, try this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String formate = df.format(value); 
double finalValue = (Double)df.parse(formate) ;
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this is 2 year old question but as every body faces a problem to round off the values at some point of time.I would like to share a different way which can give us rounded values to any scale by using `BigDecimal` class .Here we can avoid extra steps which are required to get the final value if we use    `DecimalFormat("0.00")` or using `Math.round(a * 100) / 100` .

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class RoundingNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double number = 123.13698;
        int decimalsToConsider = 2;
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number);
        BigDecimal roundedWithScale = bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Rounded value with setting scale = "+roundedWithScale);

        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number);
        BigDecimal roundedValueWithDivideLogic = bigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.ONE,decimalsToConsider,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Rounded value with Dividing by one = "+roundedValueWithDivideLogic);

    }
}
```

This program would give us below output

```
Rounded value with setting scale = 123.14
Rounded value with Dividing by one = 123.14
```

Comment: You could also use `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN` to achieve a similar logic like `Math.round()` (1.204 = 1.20, 1.205 = 1.21).

Answer (score 13):

Try :

```
class round{
public static void main(String args[]){

double a = 123.13698;
double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100;
String.format("%.3f", roundOff); //%.3f defines decimal precision you want
System.out.println(roundOff);   }}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100;
```

should be

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100D;
```

Adding 'D' to 100 makes it Double literal, thus result produced will have precision

Comment: doesnt work the result is still 123.0

Comment: I have moved 'F' to denominator now. It should work now

Comment: the output is even more messed up.
`123.13999938964844`

Answer (score 7):

**This is long one but a full proof solution, never fails**

Just pass your number to this function as a double, it will return you rounding the decimal value up to the nearest value of 5;

if 4.25, Output 4.25

if 4.20, Output 4.20

if 4.24, Output 4.20

if 4.26, Output 4.30

if you want to round upto 2 decimal places,then use

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
roundToMultipleOfFive(Double.valueOf(df.format(number)));
```

if up to 3 places, new DecimalFormat("#.###")

if up to n places, new DecimalFormat("#.**nTimes #**")

```
 public double roundToMultipleOfFive(double x)
            {

                x=input.nextDouble();
                String str=String.valueOf(x);
                int pos=0;
                for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                {
                    if(str.charAt(i)=='.')
                    {
                        pos=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                int after=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(pos+1,str.length()));
                int Q=after/5;
                int R =after%5;

                if((Q%2)==0)
                {
                    after=after-R;
                }
                else
                {
                   if(5-R==5)
                   {
                     after=after;
                   }
                   else after=after+(5-R);
                }

                       return Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0,pos+1).concat(String.valueOf(after))));

            }
```

Answer (score 6):

seems like you are hit by integer arithmetic: in some languages (int)/(int) will always be evaluated as integer arithmetic.
in order to force floating-point arithmetic, make sure that at least one of the operands is non-integer:

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100.f;
```

Comment: with
 `double roundOff = Math.round(a*100F)/100.f;`
the output is even more messed up. it is:
`123.13999938964844`

Comment: are you interested in printing the rounded number or in evaluating the rounded number (to do something with it)? if it is only printing, you should look up the documentation for println. if you are interested in the numbers, then i guess (without actually having confirmed) that the "messed" up output is actually correct, as it is the closes floating-point equivalent to "123.14" (check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems))

Comment: For future reference, replacing the "f" (of float) with a "d" (of double) should solve your issue. Not sure why, however, this should solve the problem. Maybe anyone else could elaborate on the solution.

Comment: because doubles have a much higher precision, so the double-precision equivalent of "123.14" displays as "123.14", whereas the single-precision equivalent of "123.14" displays as "123.139999"... (which btw, it doesn't with my OpenJDK 18.0.2 installation)

Comment: this doesn't work, trying with 19.685, it should become 19.69. but it is returning 19.68

Comment: it does work. the value `19.685` is represented as (an IEEE-754 float) "19.684999465942383", which correctly rounds to `16.68`.

Answer (score 2):

I just modified your code. It works fine in my system. See if this helps

```
class round{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    double a = 123.13698;
    double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100.00;

    System.out.println(roundOff);
}
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
public static float roundFloat(float in) {
    return ((int)((in*100f)+0.5f))/100f;
}
```

Should be ok for most cases. You can still changes types if you want to be compliant with doubles for instance.