# How to always round off upto 2 decimal places in java

Tags: java

I have tried the following code but it is not working in a **particular case.**

Eg: Suppose, I have a **double value=2.5045** and i want it to be rounded off upto **two** decimal places using the below code.After rounding off, i get the answer as **2.5.** But I want the answer to be **2.50 instead.** In this case,zero is trimmed off. Is there any way to retain the zero so as to get the desired answer as **2.50** after rounding off.

```
 private static DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
         public static double roundTwoDecimals(double amount) {
                return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(amount));
            }
```

Comment: `double` doesn't have a format it is just a value.  What you want is a `String` and DecimalFormat is one way to get it.

Answer (score 3):

try this pattern

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

but this will change only formatting, double cannot hold number of digits after decimal poin, try BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2.5045).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it still returns me an answer of 2.5.

Comment: try System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(2.5045));

Comment: The above code is working but i want it to convert it back to Double like the way I am doing. So while converting back to Double,the zero is trimmed off. So is there any other way around?

Comment: Now I understood. You cant have that with double. You can do what you want with BigDecimal which has precision prop.

Comment: Ya you are right. I am not able to do that with Double.Can you provide me with an example with BigDecimal if possible?

Comment: see update, you will decide if you can use it, but this thing remembers the number of digits after decimal point

Comment: Thanks for the code.It works fine.I guess this is not possible with double.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). For `#` it says:

> Digit, zero shows as absent

`0` is probably what you want:

> Digit

So what you are looking for is either `"0.00"` or `"#.00"` as a format string, depending on whether you want the first digit before the period, to be visible in case the numbers absolute value is smalle than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");  
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);  
answer.setText(format.format(data2));
```

Comment: This is working fine but the answer is in string. I want it to be converted to Double using valueOf method like the way i am doing in my code. After conversion,the trailing zero is trimmed off.So is there any way around?

Comment: @zam You can use `Double.parseDouble()` to convert a `String` to a `double`: `String text = "12.34"; // example String` `double value = Double.parseDouble(text);` For your case it looks like you want: `double total = Double.parseDouble(answer.setText(format.format(data2)));`

Comment: Thanks for the code. I just tried it. It is still giving the same.It goes well with the String. But creates a problem while doing with double value.

Comment: @zam `double d = Double.parseDouble(aString);` this would convert string to double..

Comment: @zam This works `new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00##").format(d)`

Comment: I tried the above one. It is giving me upto 4 decimal points.Rounding off is not done upto 2 decimal place.

Comment: @zam `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");` This works

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
double d = 4.85999999999;   
long l = (int)Math.round(d * 100); // truncates   
d = l / 100.0;
```

Comment: if there is a 0 at the secound decimal place and after the null a values less than 5 it prints x.x thats the problem of the op.

Comment: refer this  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: input: d = 4.800999; ouput: 4.8    and thats not the ouput he want...i tested it. it should be 4.80

Comment: its 480 and after dividing it by 100.0 its 4.8

Comment: got it... check the new answer that i have posted

Comment: i just checked the above piece of code. It is showing 4.8.

Comment: @user3301373 ya so please try the new code that i have posted that works as u expect..

Comment: think you can delete this.

Comment: i tried the above code.but stil the same.Have you edited your code already?I tried this:::  double d = 4.85999999999;   
long l = (int)Math.round(d * 100); // truncates   
d = l / 100.0;

Comment: @zam i have posted two answers one is where you get the answer in form of string(if u remember u had commented) and this. you can try what i have mentioned there .. that works fine

Comment: but the above code is giving me as 4.8.The trailing zero is trimmed off.Can you please add your code in the comment section if you dont mind?

Comment: DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");  
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);  
answer.setText(format.format(yourDoubleValue));

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `double`. But `double` or `Double` are objects representing a number and don't carry any formatting information. Ìf you need to output two decimal places the point to do this is when you convert your `double` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

use # if you want to ignore 0

```
new DecimalFormat("###,#0.00").format(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to achieve this . I have already posted answer in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java) 
will just answer again here. As we will require rounding off values many times .

```
public class RoundingNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double number = 2.5045;
        int decimalsToConsider = 2;
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number);
        BigDecimal roundedWithScale = bigDecimal.setScale(decimalsToConsider, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Rounded value with setting scale = "+roundedWithScale);

        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number);
        BigDecimal roundedValueWithDivideLogic = bigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.ONE,decimalsToConsider,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Rounded value with Dividing by one = "+roundedValueWithDivideLogic);

    }
}
```

Output we will get is

```
Rounded value with setting scale = 2.50
Rounded value with Dividing by one = 2.50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double kilobytes = 1205.6358;
double newKB = Math.round(kilobytes*100.0)/100.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
System.out.println("kilobytes (DecimalFormat) : " + df.format(kilobytes));
```

Try this if u are still getting the above problem