# Invalid double return in android

Tags: java, android, math

This is my code:

[image]

This is my first value. That is `8`.

[image]

This is my next value. That is `11`.

[image]

This is my integer value. That is `107`.

[image]

My expect return value is `271.78` but it return back me `271.78(0)3`. That make me wonder why? I tried to casting `foot` and `inch` to `double` but it not work.

[image]

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) show me how to compare but i need to return a right number. It can't help me.

Comment: Because floating-point math. There is nothing wrong here.

Comment: You can use **Math.round**: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11701527/1237175