# Rounding to the second decimal place

Tags: java, formatting

After some awesome help yesterday on this site, I am back with another question. I have my input/output equation the way I want it but need help rounding the decimal off to the hundredths position. The way it is set up now the output of pounds seems to just repeat the answer. I have been inputting 10.2 as the weight in kilograms and the answer I keep receiving in pounds is 22.4422.44. I know it is something with the String.format I am using but after messing with it for quite a while I can't seem to figure it out. I know it is something silly but I have been working on this for a while now and I think my brain may be mush. Below is my program.

```
//This program converts kilograms to pounds using input/output dialog boxes.

import javax.swing.*;

public class SNHU2_3 {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String inputStr;
        String outputStr;


        double pounds;
        double kilograms;


        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter weight in kilograms");
        kilograms = Double.parseDouble(inputStr);

        outputStr = ("Kilograms = " + kilograms) + "\n" + ("Pounds = " +  (kilograms * 2.2)) + String.format("%.2f", (kilograms * 2.2));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr, "Weight Conversion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);


    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)... did you search?

Comment: Not your immediate problem but there are **not** exactly 2.2 pounds in a kilogram. The precise number is 2.20462262185. That will cause you trouble: even with rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
    outputStr = String.format("Kilograms = %.2f \n Pounds = %.2f", kilograms, (kilograms * 2.2));
```

I would first of all suggest that you should thoroughly research your question before posting it. There are many related question that are already asked in this forum. Also study a little bit more about `String.format`.

Next to explain your problem:

```
    outputStr = ("Kilograms = " + kilograms) + "\n" + ("Pounds = " +  (kilograms * 2.2)) + String.format("%.2f", (kilograms * 2.2));
```

What this statement does is it concatenates different strings that you have placed between '+' signs. So we start from the left where your have the String `"Kilograms = "` so first it is taken then we have `kilogram` this is basically a `double` and in your example stores the value `10.2`. Now the String becomes `"Kilograms = 10.2"`. After that you have the string `"\n"`. So the string becomes `"Kilograms = 10.2\n"`. Then you have `"Pounds = "`, so on concatenation the string becomes `"Kilograms = 10.2\nPounds = "`. After that it hits the expression `(kilograms * 2.2)` Which in your case is `10.2*2.2` which computes to `22.44` So after concatenation the string becomes `"Kilograms = 10.2\nPounds = 22.44"`. After that it hits `String.format("%.2f", (kilograms * 2.2))`. The return value of this expression in your case is '"22.44"'. So now the finally concatenated string is `"Kilograms = 10.2\nPounds = 22.4422.44"` which is finally stored in `outputStr`. And this is exactly what you get.

I believe that I have been able to explain you what is the problem. **SO REMEMBER** - *you should thoroughly research your question before posting it.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. So my problem was having the "equation" in the outputStr twice?

Comment: @Ph1shPhryd I have edited my answer to explain you every thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use:

```
kilograms = Double.parseDouble(inputStr);
Math.round(kilograms);
```