# Round a double to 4 decimals or less

Tags: java, double

I'm currently using the method :

```
String.format("%.4", myDouble);
```

The trouble with this is that if I get a number with less decimals, such as 2.34, it will display 2.3400 . Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Use `DecimalFormat` to format decimals...

Comment: If you are talking about a percentage or using this in a scientific context, it might be clearer to write them all with the same number of decimals. For example, if it's exactly 2.3400% and the next number is 5.8794%, then the former should be written as 2.3400. Here, the zeroes are significant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DecimalFormat` and a pattern.

```
double value = 2.34;
String pattern = "#.####";
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
String output = myFormatter.format(value);

System.out.println(value + " " + pattern + " " + output);  // displays  2.34 #.#### 2.34
```

For more references [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 4):

Using `DecimalFormat` and pattern `#.####` should work. It will display up to 4 digits after the decimal point but it might be less if no need.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Math.round function :) example:

```
Math.round(192.15515452*10000)/10000.0
```

returns 192.1551

and `Math.round(192.15*10000)/10000.0`

returns 192.15