# Result of String.Format() is ignored but why?

Tags: java, android-studio

So I wanted to round my double values into numbers that contain only 2 decimals but cant figure out how to do it. How can I change my code in order to get 2 values that are rounded for 2 decimals? Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(numBase.getText().toString());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(numNikotin.getText().toString());
        sum = num1 / 20 * num2;
        String resultN = Double.toString(sum);
        String.format("%.2f", resultN);
        addResult.setText(resultN);
        sum = num1 - sum;
        String resultB = Double.toString(sum);
        String.format("%.2f", resultB);
        addResult2.setText(resultB);
    }
});
```

Comment: Second sentence of the [documentation for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): *Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

`String.format(...);` returns a new String. You have to assign it to a variable:

```
resultN= String.format("%.2f", sum );
```

Also the parameter must be numeric.

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) for more details

Comment: Thanks I will try to assign it. I will come back with more information about my progress in a minute hold on.

Comment: So I tried it like this, but it crashes the app when I try to run it. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below post:
[round up to 2 decimal places in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java)

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

or

```
String roundOffTo2DecPlaces(float val)
{
    return String.format("%.2f", val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String resultN = String.format("%.2f", sum);
```

why cast to string ????????

```
String resultN = Double.toString(sum);
String.format("%.2f", resultN);
```

Comment: Because I need it to calculate something.
                sum = num1 - sum;

Comment: you don't need cast to string. String resultN = String.format("%.2f", sum); is enough