# Math.pow() is returning an unexpected result

Tags: java

`Math.pow()` is returning an unexpected result for some inputs.

for ex - below is my code to find the nth root of m

```
    public class FindRoot {

   static int m,n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        findRoot(m,n);

    }

        private static void findRoot(int m, int n) {

        double tempDouble = Math.pow(m, 1.0/n);

        System.out.println(tempDouble);
      }
    }
```

Now, when i pass m = 9 & n = 2, it is giving expected result  i.e. 3.0 but if i pass m = 1000 & n = 3 then i am expected 10.0 but it is giving 9.999999999999998 i.e. unexpected result.

Comment: You might want to try `0.1 + 0.2` :)

Comment: This is how floating point numbers work

Comment: Why would expect the result to be rounded up?

Comment: This is calculated internally as `exp(ln(1000.0) * (1/3.0))` with rounding errors in each step. They accumulate to the result you get.

Comment: Use `Math.round()` to get rounded value of any value: instead of `System.out.println(tempDouble);` use `System.out.println(Math.round(tempDouble));`

Comment: use: System.out.println(Math.ceil(tempDouble)); ; BTW you cant reference non static members in static main class, so edit your question.

Comment: @thepooran - I can't use Math.round() because for many test cases ...tempDouble value could be 2.8.. or 2.7.. then i will always get an integer value which will be not accepted.

Comment: @CommonMan - I can't use Math.ceil() because for many test cases like m = 9 & n = 3...tempDouble value is 2.0800.. then Math.ceil(tempDouble) is returning 3.0

Also, there is no compile-time error with the code so don't worry abut the reference non static members in static main class.

Comment: why the hell, this thread is closed?? It needs discussion :/

Comment: @Ajay see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11701399/10485339