# Java get without rounding first 2 decimal digits of a double

Tags: java

I want to get the first 2 decimal digits (without rounding ).

Here is an example:

49455.10937 --> **49455.10**

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher This question asks for a solution without rounding

Comment: without rounding of the required digits. not without rounding operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

formatting to `String` is an expensive operation (in performance terms)
this can be done with math operations:

```
    double x = 49455.10937;
    x *= 100;  // moves two digits from right to left of dec point
    x = Math.floor(x);  // removes all reminaing dec digits
    x /= 100;  // moves two digits from left to right of dec point
```

Comment: if 2nd decimal place is 0, it gets dropped

Answer (score 0):

```
double decimalValue = 49455.10937;
String decimalValueStr = String.valueOf(decimalValue);
int indexDot = decimalValueStr.lastIndexOf('.');
int desiredDigits=3;
String decimal = decimalValueStr.substring(0, (indexDot + 1) + desiredDigits);
decimalValue = Double.parseDouble(decimal);
System.out.println(decimalValue);
//49455.109 is console output (change desired digits)
```

Comment: @chathu93 you are welcome but as Sharon said, if you are worrying about performance his piece of code is more suited for this operation

Answer (score -1):

You can use a formatter to format the double value as follows

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
Double value = 49455.10937;
System.out.println(formatter.format("The value: %.2f", value));
```

Comment: could you please add the declaration for `formatter`?

Comment: doesn't compile

Comment: Exception : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Formatter to String`