# How i round off two decimal point in java?

Tags: java, android, decimal, rounding

Like it comes : 692589
i want the value similar : 69.23

I want to know more than one process to perform this task in java

Comment: does this help ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: How is the question related to **android** and **android-studio**?

Comment: How does 692589 becomes  69.23? That's not rounding . Edit your question with a proper example .

Answer (score 0):

you can use DecimalFormat("0.00") to ensure the number is round to 2 decimal places. and maybe this can help you.
https://mkyong.com/java/java-display-double-in-2-decimal-points/#:~:text=format(%E2%80%9C%25.,double%20to%202%20decimal%20places.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).