# Problems rounding to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I've used these posts as reference:

1. [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)
2. [round up to 2 decimal places in java? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java)

After reading through the solutions to these question, I'm still having trouble rounding up to the hundredths place.
Here are what I've tried along with their outputs:

`BigDecimal`

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class RaceCarThread extends Thread {

    private static boolean raceNow = false;
    private int iterations;
    private double lapsCompleted;
    private boolean crash;
    private int nbrOfCrashes;
    
    // Default constructor
    public RaceCarThread() {
        super();
    }
    
    // Constructor for custom name
    public RaceCarThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        raceNow = true;
        lapsCompleted = 0;
        crash = false;
        nbrOfCrashes = 0;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        
        while (!(lapsCompleted >= 17)) {
            double randomNum = Math.random();
            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(randomNum).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
            randomNum = bd.doubleValue();
            lapsCompleted = lapsCompleted + randomNum;
            System.out.println(lapsCompleted);
        }
    }   
}
```

```
10.31
10.5
11.13
11.850000000000001
12.810000000000002
13.570000000000002
14.200000000000003
15.080000000000004
15.800000000000004
16.200000000000003
16.790000000000003
17.430000000000003
```

`Math.round(randomNum*100d) / 100d`

```
public class RaceCarThread extends Thread {

    private static boolean raceNow = false;
    private int iterations;
    private double lapsCompleted;
    private boolean crash;
    private int nbrOfCrashes;
    
    // Default constructor
    public RaceCarThread() {
        super();
    }
    
    // Constructor for custom name
    public RaceCarThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        raceNow = true;
        lapsCompleted = 0;
        crash = false;
        nbrOfCrashes = 0;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        
        while (!(lapsCompleted >= 17)) {
            double randomNum = Math.random();
            lapsCompleted = lapsCompleted + (Math.round(randomNum * 100d) / 100d);
            System.out.println(lapsCompleted);
        }
    }
}
```

```
11.020000000000003
11.730000000000004
12.720000000000004
13.430000000000003
13.930000000000003
14.020000000000003
14.300000000000002
15.210000000000003
15.250000000000002
15.500000000000002
16.32
17.080000000000002
```

I'm unable to use `DecimalFormat` due to using the number in calculations.

Edit: The `System.out.println(lapsCompleted)` is just for checking the values and will be removed once I fix the decimals

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken for a discussion of how computers work with floating point numbers.

Comment: Hint: Whenever you use floating point arithmetics, chances are high that numbers will be slightly 'off', because they're based on fractions. Solution #1: create your own data type that stores an int or long, and its `toString()` method inserts a dot. Solution #2: keep using float or double, but whenever you output the number, always use one of the rounding methods: BigInteger, (x*100)/100, printf(), DecimalFormat. Solution 3: write your own class, which contains a double value, and you implement its `toString()` method to format the double with one of the four methods above.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks for your help guys. It's much appreciated!

Comment: If you've read my answer in your first citation you should have seen that what you are attempting is impossible *a priori,* with proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do calculations with your decimal values, you really need to use `BigDecimal` throughout.  Never trust `double` or `float` to give accurate answers to calculations involving decimal values.

Also, when you create a `BigDecimal` from a `double`, don't use `new BigDecimal(yourDouble)`, because that just puts the floating point error that's already in your `double` into the `BigDecimal`.  It's generally much better to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(yourDouble)`, which gives you the decimal value with the least number of decimal places that your `double` is close enough to.  That sounds bad, but it's actually good, because you typically get the value that was used to create the `double` initially.

For example,

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1)); // prints 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1)); // prints 0.1
```