# Double decimal formatting in Java

Tags: java, formatting, double, decimal

I'm having some problems formatting the decimals of a double. If I have a double value, e.g. 4.0, how do I format the decimals so that it's 4.00 instead?

Comment: Try using [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) or [`java.text.Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show only two digit after decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to Format a Double value to 2 Decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

One of the way would be using [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(4.0));
```

Output:

**4.00**

Comment: Yeah, but i don't want the comma, i want a decimal sign.

Comment: I'm getting a comma. This is what i did. "double variable; NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); System.out.println(formatter.format(variable));

Comment: output for that is X,00 and not X.00

Comment: You're getting a comma because of the default language used by your JVM, which is probably different from those of Nambari. Have a look at NumberFormat javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: As zim2001 pointed, your locale might be different. Read the link  provided in my answer. At the end you will find info about this.

Comment: Optionally u might want to add another separator for digits more than 3 before the comma then use the following `NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,000.00");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(4.0));`

Answer (score 84):

With Java 8, you can use `format` method..: -

```
System.out.format("%.2f", 4.0); // OR

System.out.printf("%.2f", 4.0);
```

- `f` is used for `floating` point value..
- `2` after decimal denotes, number of decimal places after `.`

For most Java versions, you can use `DecimalFormat`: -

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    double d = 4.0;
    System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Answer (score 61):

Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

`String.format("%.2f", 4.52135);`

As per docs:

> The locale always used is the one returned by `Locale.getDefault()`.

Comment: String.format also accepts a locale as a first parameter to account for decimal sign formatting.

Comment: To avoid locale-specific decimal signs (such as a comma), specify the US locale: 
String.format(Locale.US,"%.2f", 4.52135);

Comment: I would say "to use US locale-specific dot as a decimal sign, specify the US locale" .. this idea that US habits are the right ones and everything else is kind of "folk" stuff drives me crazy.

Comment: @SimoneGianni Don't make stupid assumptions, some people might need the decimal to be a dot. For example I am writing a function that exports a CSV document, and I can't have a comma because the comma character is the delimiter.

Answer (score 23):

Using String.format, you can do this:

```
double price = 52000;
String.format("$%,.2f", price);
```

Notice the comma which makes this different from @Vincent's answer

Output:

`$52,000.00`

A good resource for formatting is the [official](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) java page on the subject

Answer (score 7):

You could always use the static method `printf from System.out` - you'd then implement the corresponding formatter; this saves heap space in which other examples required you to do.

Ex:

```
System.out.format("%.4f %n", 4.0); 

System.out.printf("%.2f %n", 4.0);
```

Saves heap space which is a pretty big bonus, nonetheless I hold the opinion that this example is much more manageable than any other answer, especially since most programmers know the printf function from C (Java changes the function/method slightly though).

Comment: @Baz Am I missing a crucial detail here, there's no printStream mentioned. The OP is asking for formatting help (which could be solved more easily by looking at the Java docs) to the standard output stream. Explain.

Comment: My bad. Was looking at the wrong javadoc version (1.4). BTW: `out` is the `PrintStream`.

Comment: @Baz No worries. Yes, I assumed that's the class you were referring to, in all my books printf is referred to as the static method from the System.out (as those methods are static).

Comment: To be exact, `printf` is a static method of `PrintStream`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) ;) But +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @Baz From the docs the printStream class inherited System.out. I could perhaps be wrong - although it is quite strange to inherit a static method (is it even possible)? You're, I expect correct though.

Comment: I can't follow you. `System.out` is an static instance of `PrintStream`. That's why you can access methods of `PrintStream` when using `System.out`.

Comment: @Baz that's fine. Thank you though.

Answer (score 5):

```
double d = 4.0;
DecimalFormat nf = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(nf.format("#.##"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use any one of the below methods

1. If you are using `java.text.DecimalFormat`

   ```
   DecimalFormat decimalFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); 
   decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2); 
   System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(4.0));
   ```

   OR

   ```
   DecimalFormat decimalFormat =  new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); 
   System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(4.0));
   ```
2. If you want to convert it into simple string format

   ```
   System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", 4.0));
   ```

All the above code will print **4.00**

Answer (score 3):

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(4.0d);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is use the `setMinimumFractionDigits` method from the `NumberFormat` class.

Here you basically specify how many numbers you want to appear after the decimal point.

So an input of `4.0` would produce `4.00`, assuming your specified amount was 2.

But, if your `Double` input contains more than the amount specified, it will take the minimum amount specified, then add one more digit rounded up/down

For example, `4.15465454` with a minimum amount of 2 specified will produce `4.155`

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
Double myVal = 4.15465454;
System.out.println(nf.format(myVal));
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/jJ9XGu)

Answer (score 0):

Works 100%.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Formatting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value = 22.2323242434342;
        // or  value = Math.round(value*100) / 100.0;

        System.out.println("this is before formatting: "+value);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");

        System.out.println("Value: " + df.format(value));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

First import `NumberFormat`. Then add this:

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

This will give you two decimal places and put a dollar sign if it's dealing with currency.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Payroll 
{
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int hoursWorked = 80;
    double hourlyPay = 15.52;

    double grossPay = hoursWorked * hourlyPay;
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.println("Your gross pay is " + currencyFormatter.format(grossPay));
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is not about displaying a currency and is more accurately answered by using formatting functions )like described in other answers).

Answer (score -4):

You can do it as follows:

```
double d = 4.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: Doesn't work because it's using `##` instead of `00`

Answer (score -4):

I know that this is an old topic, but If you really like to have the period instead of the comma, just save your result as X,00 into a String and then just simply change it for a period so you get the X.00

The simplest way is just to use replace.

```
String var = "X,00";
String newVar = var.replace(",",".");
```

The output will be the **X.00** you wanted. Also to make it easy you can do it all at one and save it into a double variable:

```
Double var = Double.parseDouble(("X,00").replace(",",".");
```

I know that this reply is not useful right now but maybe someone that checks this forum will be looking for a quick solution like this.