# Trying to multiply double by int in java

Tags: java

I am trying to multiply 1207.87 by 10000 and expecting 12078700.0 but I am getting 1.2078699999999998E7

I understand that its related to precision mistake but how do i rectify this problem

**EDIT:-**

I simply want to remove the decimal

Comment: How about using `Math.round`?

Comment: Give us some more info on what You want to do with it.

Comment: sorry guys ...small edit ..I simply want to remove the decimal

Comment: Then edit the question to reflect what you want instead of putting the real question in the comments and make us all waste time.

Comment: @m0skit0: I had already edited the question.

Comment: Can you guys please explain the Down votes. Its a perfectly legit question??

Comment: 1) You didn't formulate your question correctly 2) You changed the question in the middle of the answers 3) You changed your question in the comments instead of editing the question

Comment: @m0skit0 : 1. you can check the timestamps on the question and comment. I first update the question and then the comment 2. Changing question in the middle of answers does not even mean anything. Unanswered question is always in the midle of answers. 3. Still if you want to downvote a question due to above reasons i guess you really dont get  a reason of downvote (down vote if it will not be helpful for other people)

Comment: 1) You didn't even edit the question, someone else did it for you. 2) You cannot change your question to a different question, it's considered a bad question, you can check meta. 3) Downvoting this question is probably the best thing to do given its very poor quality and the time we wasted trying to understand what you want, and then you change your question. IMHO this is disrespectful for people trying to help you. So yeah, downvote stays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
1207.87f * 10000
```

the result will be:

```
1.20787E7
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because of *float numbers representation*.
You can:

- round it `Math.round(...)`
- or use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you need high precision.

More about [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution. You won't get 120700.0 but 120700 (one is a decimal number while the other is an integer), and also you will lose all decimals for other operation values, which will solve problem for these values but break it for all other values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the CAST:

```
(int) 1207.87 * 10000
```

Comment: @m0skit0:- See the edit which OP made in comments! `sorry guys ...small edit ..I simply want to remove the decimal `

Comment: So the real question is in the comments... Brilliant.

Comment: @m0skit0:- I tried to edit the question so that it becomes readable and understandable to the new people watching it. Hope that makes sense now! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rectify this if you use `double` type. You can if you use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use decimal format like:

```
 DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
 f.format(Double.valueOf(yourDouble));
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

double are stored in exponental precision in java and many other languages. see [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)for more information about float, double and their variant

If you want a integer result, then cast your floating point number, or the result. If you want to just print a floating number in "ordinary notation", then you can use the class `NumberFormat`

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(4.0));
```

example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java)

finally you can use a fixed precision number with the class BigDecimal, but please take care that this is normally not hardware (FPU) accelerated so will slow down a lot your calculation, but will give you fixed error. That kind of number is especially used in simulation where error must be know

Comment: `120700.0` is not an integer result.

Comment: OP didn't specify precision needed, so i'm giving all the solution i know. also added BigDecimal

Comment: What I mean is that if he says *"I expect 120700.0"* then he's not expecting 120700.

Comment: Ok, then he will probably follow one of the other 2 solution, with formatter or bigdecimal

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatted output as below:

```
double ans = 1207.87 * 10000;
System.out.printf("ans: %.0f\n", ans);
```

Output:

```
ans: 12078700
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way would be this one:

```
Double j = 1207.87; 
int x = j.intValue(); 
System.out.println(x * 10000);
```

Comment: That would kill the .87