# rounding a float to 7 significant digits in java

Tags: java

I get an float number as output from an method i want to round it to 7 significant digits.For ex:

> if 1.234 output should be 1.234000
>
> if 7.1232478 output should be 7.123248

I tried

```
sum=sum*1000000/1000000;

System.out.println(Float.toString(sum).substring(0,8));
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java

Comment: The link doesn't specifically mention the rounding issue. The answers there can easily be extended to cover it though, I have added an answer showing the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the result, use `System.out.printf(".7f");` or `String.format(".7f")` :

```
System.out.printf("%.7f\n", 1.123456789123456789);
```

> 1.1234568

Is you want to compute something, look at `BigDecimal`

```
//For example, divide by 1 and give a prevision of 7 digits
BigDecimal divide = bigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.ONE, 7, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(divide);
```

> 1.1234568

Comment: @amit In order to avoid problems with precision, the OP should use BigDecimal only. : `new BigDecimal("2.9");`

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` has this feature

```
System.out.printf ("%.7f", floatNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)** to format numbers.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.000000");
String result = df.format(1.234);
System.out.println(result);
```

> 1.234000

**Quick Reference link**

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/decimalformat/java-decimal-format-example/

Answer (score 1):

String class has a format method in it. you can use that.

```
String number=String.format("%.7f", 1.234567777);
```

number variable will have desired result i.e. (1.2345678)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1, create DecimalFormat (example is number with 7 decimal places, replaces with zeros if smaller than 7)

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.#######");
```

Step 2, set the rounding mode (chosen mode is just an example, choose one that suits you best)

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Step 3, format number

```
String myNumber = df.format(1.234);
```