# How to remove scientific notation from double

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a bean which has a property of type double. When I pass this bean to view layer, it shows the value in scientific notation For example: 9.78313E+10 instead of 97831300000.

I want the result without scientific notation and I cannot change the data type of that field. Please let me know if there is any workaround.

Comment: Seems you want to format this double value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `printf()` with `%f`:

```
System.out.printf("%.0f", value);
```

Here you can find a beautiful [printf format cheat sheet](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) by Alvin Alexander that might help you (and hopefully others) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How the number is shown depends on the **formatting** that is used by the component showing the value. If you can't access that code to use a different formater; then there is nothing you can do.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html for starters.

One option might be: can you exchange the bean implementation; so instead of providing a "double" number; can you change it to provide a string (in that case, you could control the formatting of the number).