# How do I get String.format %.2 to go to decimal points in Eclipse?

Tags: java, string, format

I'm trying to get my code to format to two decimal places and I use

```
venus=String.format("%.2f",planetVenus);
```

but the final output still uses more than 2 decimal points.

Comment: I think this might be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java