# Format a Double number at 2 decimals when printing in Java

Tags: java, decimal

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //Greeting and explanation of program
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("I am going to help you keep track of fuel consumption "
            + "by converting the metric system into miles and gallons.\n");

    System.out.print("How many kilometers have you driven?\n");
    double kilometers =keyboard.nextDouble();

    double milePerKilometer = Math.round(kilometers/1.609);

    System.out.printf("You drove: "+ milePerKilometer + " miles.\n\n");

    System.out.print("How many liters of gas have you purchased?\n");
    double liters = keyboard.nextDouble();

    double gallonPerLiter = Math.round(liters/3.785);

    System.out.printf("You purchased: "+ gallonPerLiter + " gallons of gas.\n\n");

    double milePerGallon = (milePerKilometer/gallonPerLiter);

    System.out.printf("So your car is getting " + milePerGallon +
            " miles per gallon.");

}
```

One the last line I am supposed to have the MPG rounded to two decimal places. I am not sure how to do this. I heard that I am supposed to add *%.2f* in there somewhere, but don't know where.

Comment: [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double decimal formatting in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since string.format you can use:

```
String.format("%02d", yourNumber)
```

or just doing like:

```
System.out.printf("So your car is getting %02d miles per gallon.", milePerGallon);
```

Comment: Does that require using a different class?

Comment: so it would look like: System.out.printf("So your car is getting " + milePerGallon +  "%02d", miles per gallon.");

Comment: nope, I just edited and updated the answer, take a look and let me know

Comment: That's awesome! People have showed that before, but it never made sense until now. Thank you!

Comment: Wait. its still not working. When i try different ways of answering, it runs the decimal point long.