# Why does this method always produce 0 as its return value?

Tags: java, for-loop

So I keep receiving the answer of `0` regardless of the inputs to the method. When I input `6` months, `100` savings amount, and `0.05` interest rate it should give me `608.81` but the response is `0`. I feel like it could be my `for` loop or the parameters that I have set that are messing with it. I have tried all I can think of regarding the `for` loop. Here's the code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FifthAssignment2 {

    static double savingAmount = 0.0; // the 2 given static doubles
    static double annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    static int numberOfMonth;
    static double sixthMonth = 0.0;;

    public static double compoundValueMethod(double savingAmount, double annualInterestRate, int NumberOfMonth) {

        {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".00");

        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;

        if (savingAmount < 0)
            if (annualInterestRate < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Both of your values are negative!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        if (savingAmount < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Your savings amount is negative!");
        }

        else if (annualInterestRate < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Your annual interest rate is negative!");
        }

        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonth; i++) {
                sixthMonth = ((savingAmount+sixthMonth) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate));
            }
        }
        return sixthMonth;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".00");

        int numberOfMonth;                                                  


        String NOM = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many months? ");
        numberOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(NOM);

        String SA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your savings amount? "); 

        savingAmount = Double.parseDouble(SA); 

        String AIR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the annual interest rate? "); // Window pops up
        annualInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(AIR); 

        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total compounded value after 6 months is "
                    + compoundValueMethod(savingAmount, annualInterestRate, numberOfMonth));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the following variables to your method :

```
public static double compoundValueMethod(double savingAmount,
                                         double annualInterestRate,
                                         int NumberOfMonth)
```

Note but use the static variable `numberOfMonth` in your method instead of the passed `NumberOfMonth` parameter (variable names in Java are case sensitive). `numberOfMonth` is initialized to `0` by default, so your for loop is not entered and the method returns 0.

You should eliminate the static variables and only use local variables. Had you done that in the first place, you'd get a compilation error which would make it much easier to find your bug.

Comment: Wow. This whole time for one capitalized letter. Thank you so much!!

Comment: if you don't mind me asking how would I format it to where it only uses two decimal places. previously I was using formatter.format

Comment: @josh102894 check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You dont need static variables.
Update code as below

public class FifthAssignment2 {

```
public static double compoundValueMethod(double savingAmount, double annualInterestRate, int numberOfMonth) {
    {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".00");
        double sixthMonth = 0.0;
        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;

        if (savingAmount < 0)
            if (annualInterestRate < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Both of your values are negative!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        if (savingAmount < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Your savings amount is negative!");
        }

        else if (annualInterestRate < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Your annual interest rate is negative!");
        }

        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonth; i++) {
                sixthMonth = ((savingAmount+sixthMonth) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate));
            }
        }
        return sixthMonth;
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".00");

    int numberOfMonth;                                                  


    String NOM = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many months? ");
    numberOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(NOM);


    double savingAmount; 

    String SA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your savings amount? "); 

    savingAmount = Double.parseDouble(SA); 






    String AIR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the annual interest rate? "); // Window
    // pops
    // up

    double annualInterestRate;
    annualInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(AIR); 

    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total compounded value after 6 months is "
                + compoundValueMethod(savingAmount, annualInterestRate, numberOfMonth));
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use `NumberOfMonth` instead of `numberOfMonth`

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfMonth; i++) {
                sixthMonth = ((savingAmount+sixthMonth) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate));
            }
```

or inside method you can assign

```
numberOfMonth=NumberOfMonth;
```