# What is a clever way to limit the digits of a double?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to manage doubles that go in a range of:

from `0,000001` to `999.999,999999`

What I want to achieve is to reduce this number taking in account only the 6 more important digits.

This means that for the number: `100.000,123`
I want to get `100.000`

Whereas for the number: `12,123456`
I want to get `12,1234`

And for `0,123456`
I want to get `0,123456`

And for `0'000001`
I want to get `0'000001`

Any clever procedure to get to it?
Thanks!

Comment: `((long)(myDouble * 1000000))/1000000d ?`

Comment: Hmm, why would you want to though? You're essentially wanting to remove some of the accuracy of a double?

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: @Bohemian, your solution does not do the job I think...
ThomasCook, exactly, I want to drop some accuracy, for presentation reasons.
azro, I dont agree with your perspective. I dont want to bias the responses with my failed attempts.

Comment: I guess you don't really want to drop some accuracy on a double, you just want to format the output string for presentation reasons. [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java)

Comment: @Oneiros, exactly, but numberFormat is not doing the specific job I am looking for.

Comment: Just convert your double in a string and take the first 7 characters

Comment: Yes, I did another question because this has been downvoted, I was looking for something more elegant and performing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870610/performing-way-to-limit-double-accuracy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performing way to limit double accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870610/performing-way-to-limit-double-accuracy)

Comment: @edutesoy Why did you open a duplicate question rather than improving this one? You've been around SO long enough to know where the edit button is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's some clever way to use regex for this, but here's one inefficient way that it can be done:

```
double d = ...

String s = Double.toString(d);

s = s.substring(0, Math.min(s.startsWith("0") ? 8 : 7, s.length()));

d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

It should be possible with the use of existing formatters, which I'll look into shortly and update this answer if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, as this question has been downvoted and critizised, I did another one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870610/performing-way-to-limit-double-accuracy with more accurate description.

Comment: A downvoted question isn't an excuse to open another :P