# Java get CPU usage percentage of cores

Tags: java, performance, cpu, monitoring, cpu-usage

I want to get total CPU usage of all cores. I need to print something like this:

```
Cpu 1: 33%
Cpu 2: 12%
Cpu 3: 66%
Cpu 4: 100%
```

I tried to use this code:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
int availableProcessors = operatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors();
long prevUpTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
long prevProcessCpuTime = operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();
double cpuUsage;
try
{
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
catch (Exception ignored) { }

operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
long upTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime();
long processCpuTime = operatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime();
long elapsedCpu = processCpuTime - prevProcessCpuTime;
long elapsedTime = upTime - prevUpTime;

cpuUsage = Math.min(99F, elapsedCpu / (elapsedTime * 10000F * availableProcessors));
System.out.println("Java CPU: " + cpuUsage);
```

But this code gives me output like this: `Java CPU: 27.504911422729492`.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: so what? you want to [format a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)?

Comment: I need to get information about all cores and their load. This piece of code gives me information about one core maybe. I need something like "htop" command in linux environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaSysMon](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon) uses OS-specific approach e.g. on Linux it parses `/proc/cpuinfo` to enumerate the cores. For the actual CPU core utilisation it parses the `/proc/stat` file (see [LinuxMonitor](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jezhumble/javasysmon/LinuxMonitor.java#L139)).

Comment: Thank you! Can you please provide a piece of code with output of 4 cores and their usages?