# How to Show only two Digits after Decimal

Tags: java, android

I **want to show only two digits after decimal**, i have tried but still i am *getting many digits* after decimal :

```
itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
txt_total.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(itemamount));

edit_qty_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (!edit_qty_code.getText().toString().equals("")
|| !edit_qty_code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
itemquantity = Double.parseDouble(edit_qty_code.getText().toString());
itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
txt_total.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format (itemquantity * itemamount));
} else { txt_total.setText("0.00");}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rakesh use this link:

[Show only two digit after decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal)

```
  i=348842.
  double i2=i/60000;
  DecimalFormat dtime = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
  i2= Double.valueOf(dtime.format(time));
  v.setText(String.valueOf(i2));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure where in your code you are wanting to do this, but

```
String.format("%.2f", value);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help you.

```
float localresult =Float.parseFloat(itemquantity*itemamount);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(localresult));
bd = bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
bd.doubleValue();
```

then set it to textview , textview.setText(""+bd.doubleValue();)

Answer (score 0):

Well if the value of decimal number is dynamic and if not, then here is the solution. (This solution is for both unknown dynamic value or Known value)

```
 try {
        Double rounded= new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(getdecimalvalue())).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        textviewid.setText (String.valueOf(rounded) );

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        textviewid.setText (getdecimalvalue());
    }
```

For upto 2 decimal i give setScale first parameter as 2. 
Assuming getdecimalvalue() returns a string.

For dynamic suppose if the value is "12.5" then this will throw exception and in catch you directly show the value because value is only upto 1 decimal place after point.