# Double value with specific precision in java

Tags: java, double

I'm programming a simple java program. I need to get a string from input and divide it into two parts: 1-double 2-string.
Then I need to do a simple calculation on the double and send the result to the output with specific precision(4). It works fine, but there is a problem when the input is 0, then it doesn't work properly.

For example for these input, output will be:

1 kg
output:2.2046

3.1 kg
output:6.8343

But when the input is 0, the output should be 0.0000, but it shows 0.0 .
What should I do to force it to show 0.0000?

I read similar post about double precision, they suggest something like `BigDecimal` class, but I can't use them in this case,
my code for doing this is:

```
line=input.nextLine();
array=line.split(" ");
value=Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
type=array[1];
value =value*2.2046;
String s = String.format("%.4f", value);
value = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.print(value+" kg\n");
```

Comment: Try "%0.4f". That means 'format a floating point value, pad it with zeros until you have 4 digits'.

Comment: i used "%.4f", but it shows this error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: 0.4f

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal but this is not a duplicate of that because of the formatting wanted for 0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`DecimalFormat` will allow you to define how many digits you want to display. A '0' will force an output of digits even if the value is zero, whereas a '#' will omit zeros.

`System.out.print(new DecimalFormat("#0.0000").format(value)+" kg\n");` should to the trick.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Note: if used frequently, for performance reasons you should instantiate the formatter only once and store the reference: `final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");`. Then use `df.format(value)`.

Comment: I already did, replace your last line which prints out your value.

Comment: it worked for me, but please change it to ("#0.0000"), your answer's out put is .0000 , but if we use ("#0.0000") , it show 0.0000, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

add this instance of DecimalFormat to the top of your method:

```
DecimalFormat four = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000"); // will round and display the number to four decimal places. No more, no less.

// the four zeros after the decimal point above specify how many decimal places to be accurate to.
// the zero to the left of the decimal place above makes it so that numbers that start with "0." will display "0.____" vs just ".____" If you don't want the "0.", replace that 0 to the left of the decimal point with "#"
```

then, call the instance "four" and pass your double value when displaying:

```
double value = 0;
System.out.print(four.format(value) + " kg/n"); // displays 0.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the `BigDecimal` class for calculating with floating point values. You will be able to control the precision of the floating point arithmetic. But back to the topic :)

You could use the following:

```
static void test(String stringVal) {
    final BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(stringVal).multiply(new BigDecimal("2.2046"));
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
    System.out.println(df.format(value) + " kg\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("0");
    test("1");
    test("3.1");
}
```

will give you the following output:

```
0,0000 kg

2,2046 kg

6,8343 kg
```

Comment: Thanks for your info, i didn't know how use bigDecimal to set precision.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.format("%.4f kg\n", 0.0d)` prints '0.0000 kg'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format your double value to fixed precision string output.

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats
>   decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it
>   possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support
>   for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits. It also supports different
>   kinds of numbers, including integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4), percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be localized.

Example -

```
System.out.print(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(value)+" kg\n");
```

Comment: your answer and blacklight's answer are what i want, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

String.format is just makign a String representation of the floating point value. If it doesnt provide a flag for a minimum precision, then just pad the end of the string with zeros.

Comment: BlackLight's answer looks better.

Comment: i used your suggestion, but it doesn't work, as you said BlackLight's answer is what i want, Thanks,

Comment: It's impossible for my answer to "not work" :D It's just adding "0"'s to a string. It is a sub-optimal solution though. No point re-inventing wheels!

Comment: i think it doesn't work because of this part `value=Double.parseDouble(array[0]);`

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi I meant add the padding on the resultant String :) That's what (i presume) decimalformat will be doing internally.

Comment: LOL, Sorry i have english problem, :)