# java how to change this 2.52E-5 to this 0.0000252?

Tags: java

Just like in subject: i've got double like this:

```
2.52E-5
```

what i need is this:

```
0.0000252
```

and my only idea how to do it is make sth like this:

```
public Double change(Double d){
    String do = Double.toString(d);
    String[] a = do.split("E");
    double b = Double.parseDouble(a[0]);
    double c = Double.parseDouble(a[1]);
    Double result = (Double)Math.pow(b, c);
    return result;
}
```

But I'm just curious if there is already a ready method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946388/double-value-with-specific-precision-in-java

Comment: Use `NumberFormat` or `String` fomatter

Comment: I love the way you've tackled this - very creative but alas incorrect. Don't confuse *data* with *formatting*.

Comment: so you want to convert a double to a double ? well you don't need formatting

Comment: Dont try to convert it , try to take it in the right format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf()` like:

```
System.out.printf("%f\n", value);
```

Or `DecimalFormat` look this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

Or very simply with `BigDecimal` and `toPlainString`:

```
new BigDecimal(value).toPlainString()
```

Comment: It returns an error : `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String`

Comment: on which line? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Ok, nevermind... I've forgot that this is String and it contains some letters, it works great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are the same number already. For example, on [Java Repl](http://www.javarepl.com) you can do

```
java> 0.0000252 == 2.52e-5
java.lang.Boolean res0 = true
```