# How to trim values showing in double?

Tags: java, android

I am devloping an app in which i am getting value like mentioned in statement and i have a value in double as.I need to get three digit value after "."
How can i do that

value

```
9.690000000000001
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal

Answer (score 1):

you can use `String.format("%.3f", d)`

This will round your double to 3 decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DecimalFormat`

```
Double doub=Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.###").format(9.690000000000001));
```

**note** It will return only upto two decimal positions if the third digit is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format` like:

```
Double formattedDouble = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", doubleVariable));
Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Formatted double is: " + formattedDouble);
```

`%.2f` rounds the variable up to two decimal places.

Or, you can use `java.util.Formatter` which works in the same way.

Also,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Note the `00`, meaning exactly two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
double d = 9.690000000000001;
d = (double)Math.round(d * 1000) / 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are three ways to do this:

- get_double = (double)(Math.round(result_value*1000)/1000.0)
- DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
  get_double = Double.ParseDouble(df.format(result_value));
- BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(result_value);
  BigDecimal  bd2 = bd.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  get_double = Double.ParseDouble(bd2.ToString());