# How to Format double data from database and set into Textview using comma as decimal divider on Android

Tags: android, number-formatting

I have field on table as double (money data field), and i want to put it on Textview in format for example: 
money= 20.0
i want to show as: 20,0
or money = 190.25
i want to show as: 190,25

how to do that? this is my variable

```
txtTotalBill.setText(String.valueOf(total_bill));
```

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Thank you @ZakiPathan! the answer is working! sorry for the late reply

Comment: welcome @Bayuwibawa happy to help you :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String total = String.valueOf(total_bill);    

total = total.replace(".", ",");
```

try this and then settext hope it helps

```
txtTotalBill.setText(total.toString());
```

Or you can directly setText without variable like this:

```
txtTotalBill.setText(String.valueOf(total_bill).replace('.', ','));
```

Comment: the solution works great, but i also need it become 2 digit after comma, this only replace the dot into comma, can we do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10959430/7320259 check this. First covert string into double and do needfull with above link. Hope it helps @BayuWibawa

Comment: the url you gave is not working if i only has 1 digit decimal like my example: 20.0, so i want to set 20,00 instead, can we do it?

Comment: nevermind, @ZakiPathan! i found it, must do String.format("%.2f", d) first then replace it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the String method replace to format your chain :

```
txtTotalBill.setText(String.valueOf(total_bill).replace('.', ','));
```