# How do I get rid of a few decimal points in java?

Tags: java

I have this program that resembles a fight and each attack does a random damage amount from a range of two numbers, eg., an attack can do damage from 60ish to 70ish. I say 'ish' because everytime I display the damage amount, it gives a really big decimal number like 70.28326772002643.

I want to know how to make it so that it still displays decimals, but much less, like 70.28. How do I do this?

This is not a duplicate because the other question has python syntax, and I want to know how to do it in Java.

Also, it is not a duplicate because my type is a double, not a float.

Comment: Check out `System.out.printf` as well as the mentioned `format` specifier documentation.

Comment: The contributor does not seem to want to print out the value (As your comments above have answers for), they want to store it in a decimal.

So, its a duplicate of [Show Only Two Digit After Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal)

Comment: @ThomasRokicki Which itself is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the trick for you:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d1=70.28326772002643;
        double d1rounded=Math.round(d1 * 100.0) / 100.0;
        System.out.println(d1rounded);

        double d2=70.28726772002643;
        double d2rounded=Math.round(d2 * 100.0) / 100.0;
        System.out.println(d2rounded);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
70.28
70.29
```

I also recommend you check [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) for some better ways.

Comment: No it won't. Fails most of the time, as it must. See my answer in the duplicate for proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your output is `double output = 70.28326772002643`;

Do,

```
DecimalFormat deci = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

double newOutput = deci.format(output);
```

newOutput will be equal to 70.28

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method, or [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```java
> double d = 1.23456;
> System.out.printf("%.2f\n", d);
1.23

> System.out.printf("%.3f\n", d);
1.235

> String.format("%.2f", d);
"1.23" (String)
> String.format("%.3f", d);
"1.235" (String)
```

Answer (score -1):

round() function can convert from double to integer, you can multiply 100 and then divide 100 to get 2 decimal place.

```
    double pi = Math.PI;
    double pi_round = 0.01* Math.round(pi * 100);
    System.out.println(pi_round);
```