# Formatting string number into double variable with two number after decimal point

Tags: java, double, decimal

I'm getting from server a string value formatted as follow: **14.5000**
I need to create a double variable from it with two number after decimal point: **14.50**. I've tried the following:

```
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,00");
     Double priceD = Double.parseDouble((produitParam.item(paramNb).getTextContent()));
     String dx = df.format(priceD);
     produit.setPrixTtc(Double.valueOf(dx));
```

And I'm getting **14.5**. If I use **DecimalFormat("#.00")**, it gives me **15**...

Someone could help me with that ?

Comment: try this pattern for decimal format - "###.##"

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 15... for DecimalFormat("#.00")? I have tried to run on my machine and it's result is 14.50.

Answer (score 2):

If you want string with precision upto 2 points after decimal you should use

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

you have used "#,00"

',' is used for specifying grouping Separator.

for more information here is the Java Doc of DecimalFormat:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

you should look this link.There is a lot of answer your question.

I think.The best answer is  `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");`
 for you in link

[[how to convert double to 2 number after the dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415733/how-to-convert-double-to-2-number-after-the-dot][1])

Comment: I've just figure out that it's the function **Double.parseDouble((produitParam.item(paramNb).getTextContent()));** that removes all the zeros.... is their a way to convert directly a string to double with 2 number after the decimal point ?

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
      String a = "14.5800";
       Double priceD = Double.parseDouble(a);
       String dx = df.format(priceD);
       
       System.out.println(Double.valueOf(dx));    if i run this code in my machine.it work right.this function didnt removes all the zeros.

Comment: It's not possible. The method **Double.parseDouble** is known for removing all zeros. (http://www.coderanch.com/t/385764/java/java/covert-String-double-loosing-precision). I've decided to use BigDecimal instead