# Issue in Decimal Points

Tags: java, rounding, decimalformat

I am facing an issue in decimal point I want to get only two decimal points only so I used this below code

```
 public class TestDateExample1 {
  public static void main(String[] argv){
      double d = 2.34568;
         DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
         System.out.println(f.format(d));
    }
  }
```

when I run this code the output is 2.35 but I dont need any increment when the decimal point is  higher than "5" I need exact decimal point like 2.34.

Comment: You mean you do not want the number be **round**ed?

Comment: `System.out.println(String.valueOf(d).substring(0,4)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert double to 2 number after the dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415733/how-to-convert-double-to-2-number-after-the-dot)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`DecimalFormat#setRoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode-java.math.RoundingMode-) to control how the rounding is done, and specify you always want to round down (truncate):

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
f.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode()` needs to be set to `RoundingMode.FLOOR`

Comment: As @Mureinik mentioned, it's better to use `RoundingMode.DOWN` in order to support the case where the double is negative. That is, unless the OP intends to round in the opposite direction if the number is negative ;)