# How should I calculate value in JTable column value properly?

Tags: java, swing, parsing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and I want to add the column values. I am trying this code:

```
try{
    double t = 0.00;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    int rows = empTbl.getRowCount();
    for(int row =0; row<=rows; row++) 
    {
        String am = (String) empTbl.getValueAt(row, 7);
        double d = (double) df.parse(am);
        double ans = d+t;
        jLabel7.setText("Total Sale : "+ans);
    }
}
catch(ParseException ex){ }
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: double ans = d+t, t seems to be 0.0 always. what o/p you are getting?

Comment: *"Why is this code not working?"*  Change `catch(ParseException ex){ }` to `catch(ParseException ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }` and try it again.  **Don't ignore exceptions.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- to try to avoid any parse in Java, there are proper data types
- add Double / Long / Integer value to the XxxTableModel or JTable directly (depends of unknow code, your issue)
- change the getColumnClass in XxxTableModel to the Double / Long / Integer
- add TableModelListener and override setValueAt(proper formula) then to allow formula if value in the JTables Cell changed
- [Double / Float hasn't decimal places (I*d*i*o*t*i*c thread, with interesting!!! downvoters)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553827/714968)
- use XxxTableCellRenderer for formating output to the Swing GUI

Comment: +1 for using proper data types. Also, the DecimalFormat should be used by a renderer. See [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an example.