# rounding double in java

Tags: java, file, matlab, double, rounding

I have a double valued diagonal matrix stored in a text file.

```
size(file)~410 Mo
```

I would like to reduce the size by rounding my double values.

If its a good idea, how to do it in java

```
0.1706524958886193=>0.17
```

I need to use this file later in matlab

when i try

dlmread(file) i get out of memory error

Comment: Are you storing this file as text, or as straight binary?

Comment: as a file text (.txt)// i need to use it later in matlab program

Comment: Just use e.g. [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to format as required.

Comment: Look at `DecimalFormat` class to format your doubles.

Comment: @eternay he want's to round off

Comment: Are you storing the non-diagonal elements?

Comment: @nawara is it sufficient to reduce size...or rounding is must?

Comment: @pinkpanther ; my goal is to reduce size because i will use this file later in a matlab program

Comment: have you tried [`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)?

Comment: @Jacob Math.round (0.1706524958886193)=0

Comment: @nawara my mistake, i forgot Java doesn't have a form that takes a second parameter. `Math.round(num * 100) / 100.0` will work, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you round the values you are throwing away precision. That may change the results you will get.

A better approach is to store only the diagonal items. There is no point in storing the n^2-n off-diagonal zeroes. Use the diag function to convert a vector into a diagonal matrix. http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diag.html

Even more efficient: store the numbers in a binary format instead of text.

Comment: +1 because I agree that reducing to 2 decimals might alter the results.

Comment: great idea but ....the same problem with function diag =out of memory

Comment: Then the matrix is just too big to process with the memory currently assigned to Matlab. There's a pagewith information on how to give Matlab more memory and tips on how to reduce memory cconsumption here: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html

Comment: yes thanks , i asked about this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971111/out-of-memory-error-when-using-diag-function-in-matlab/16974023?noredirect=1#16974023):

Answer (score 2):

Use `DecimalFormat` class to format the `double` value to your needs. For example, if you want to keep only 2 digits after decimal point use, `"#0.00` and so on. `DecimalFormat#format` class returns `String` output which you can use to instantiate `Double` value.
from

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Tester
{
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws Throwable
  {
    double bigDouble=0.1706524958886193;
    DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    String numberString=df.format(bigDouble);
    double smallDouble=new Double(numberString);
    System.out.println(smallDouble);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: +1 As it is the best solution to round numbers.

Comment: +1 and please to add implemented methods in [NumberFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582656/714968), otherwise you have to use BigDecimal

Comment: [true is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7553827/714968)  by @EJP

Comment: @mKorbel please to add? I didn't get you...you want' me to edit my answer or?

Comment: not there isn't something from my linked answer, nor to edit something, do you have any issue with my comments or

Comment: @mKorbel  `please to add implemented methods in NumberFormat, otherwise you have to use BigDecimal`... I didn't get that sentence...I don't have an issue :)

Comment: @pinkpanther ignore that, doesn't matter, empty answer

Comment: exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,17"`

Comment: @nawara use the methods from the NumberFormat class for convertion....note that DecimalFormat is a subclass of number format..   see this question for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888088/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-double-in-java-using-a-specific-locale

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question you can do it like this:

```
double value = 0.1706524958886193;
value = (double)((int)(value*100))/100; // returns 0.17
```

Comment: That would be truncation. The asker seems to want rounding

Comment: Also, in most cases this will not produce an "exact" result...