# out of memory error when using diag function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, out-of-memory, rounding

I have an array of valued double M where size(M)=15000

I need to convert this array to a diagonal matrix with command diag(M)

but i get the famous error `out of memory`

I run matlab with option -nojvm to gain memory space

and with the optin 3GB switch on windows

i tried also to convert my array to double precision

but the problem persist

any other idea?

Comment: That array alone is 1.8GB.  if you have any other large data structures, you're going to run out.

Comment: Can you change your variable types? Try this: `A = diag(uint16(1:50000));`.

Comment: @pm89 the array values are <1 so this command turn all of them equal to 0

Comment: What does `size(M)=15000` mean? The size function never returns a scalar. Is `M` a 15000-by-15000 matrix or a 15000-by-1 vector (or 1-by-15000)? Are you converting a vector to a diagonal matrix? Or are you trying to extract the diagonal from `M` and then possibly calling `diag(diag(M))`? All of these are different.

Comment: And do you mean that you tried to convert to single precision? You said that `M` was a double array. Converting to single precisions will only cut memory use by half and will greatly reduce numerical precision.

Comment: I doesn't use `size(M)` as matlab funtion so it mean the size of my column vector M which i would to convert it to 15000-by15000 diagonal matrix

Answer (score 3):

There are much better ways to do whatever you're probably trying to do than generating the full diagonal matrix (which will be extremely sparse).

Multiplying that matrix, which has 225 million elements, by other matrices will also take a very long time.

I suggest you restructure your algorithm to take advantage of the fact that:

```
diag(M)(a, b) =
                   M(a)    | a == b
                   0       | a != b
```

You'll save a huge amount of time and memory and whoever is paying you will be happier.

This is what a diagonal matrix looks like:

[image]

Every entry except those along the **diagonal** of the matrix (the ones where row index equals the column index) is zero.  Relating this example to your provided values, `diag(M) = A` and `M(n) = An`

Comment: can you explain more ur idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Use saprse matrix

```
 M = spdiags( M, 0, numel(M), numel(M) );
```

For more info see matlab doc on [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) and on [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `n`-by-`n` square matrix, `M`, you can directly extract the diagonal elements into a row vector via

```
n = size(M,1);    % Or length(M), but this is more general
D = M(1:n+1:end); % 1-by-n vector containing diagonal elements of M
```

If you have an older version of Matlab, the above may even be faster than using `diag` (if I recall, `diag` wasn't always a compiled function). Then, if you need to save memory and only need the diagonal of `M` and can get rid of the rest, you can do this:

```
M(:) = 0;         % Zero out M
M(1:n+1:end) = D; % Insert diagonal elements back into M
clear D;          % Clear D from memory
```

This should not allocate much more than about `(n^2+n)*8 = n*(n+1)*8` bytes at any one time for double precision values (some will needed for indexing operations). There are other ways to do the above that might save a bit more if you need a (full, non-sparse) `n`-by-`n` diagonal matrix, but there's no way to get around that you'll need `n^2*8` bytes at a minimum just to store the matrix of doubles.

However, you're still likely to run into problems. I'd investigate sparse datatypes as @user2379182 suggests. Or rework you algorithms. Or better yet, look into obtaining 64-bit Matlab and/or a 64-bit OS!