# Rounding float/decimal to 3 decimal places exactly?

Tags: java, math, rounding, precision

I know there are many questions asking for this, but I have tried quite a few of the solutions but none seem to work exactly how I need it!

Most solutions work, however in my test data I have the `float`: `0.08095238095238096`

If I round this to 4 I seem to get; `0.081` when I need to have `0.0809` and not rounded up that last place.

Also am I best using float or double for this type of number?

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is your original number is wrong. If you need to get `0.809` you'll need to start with `0.8095238095238096` (not `0.08095238095238096` as you have).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to want to round down to FOUR decimal places instead of rounding half up.

```
double d = 0.08095238095238096;
d = (long) (d * 10000) / 10000.0;
```

or

```
d = Math.floor(d * 10000) / 10000.0;
```

I assume you mean you want d = 0.0809 instead of 0.809.

Perhaps you are thinking of 3 significant digits which is a harder problem.

Its best to use `double` or `BigDecimal` instead of `float` unless you have a very good reason.

BTW: It is useful to have a clear idea of what you want, otherwise its going to be much harder to find it. ;)