# Convert a number to 2 decimal places in Java

Tags: java, decimal

I want to convert a number to a 2 decimal places (Always show two decimal places) in runtime. I tried some code but it only does, as shown below

```
 20.03034 >> 20.03
 20.3 >> 20.3  ( my code only rounds not converts )
```

however, I want it to do this:

```
 20.03034 >> 20.03
 20.3 >> 20.30 (convert it to two decimal places)
```

My code below:

```
angle = a variable
angle_screen =  a variable

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
angle = Double.valueOf(df.format(angle));
angle_screen.setText(String.valueOf(angle) + tmp);
```

Any help on how to do this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Your code is flawed somehow. You convert a double to a string with a special format. Then you convert it back to a double and then you convert it back to a string without specifying any format. I guess that's wrong. Also the purpose of the `tmp` variable is not obvious.

Comment: You should read the `DecimalFormat` API - the answer is there and it is quite clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

try this `new DecimalFormat("#.00");`

**update**:

```
    double angle = 20.3034;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    String angleFormated = df.format(angle);
    System.out.println(angleFormated); //output 20.30
```

Your code wasn't using the decimalformat correctly

The 0 in the pattern means an obligatory digit, the # means optional digit.

**update 2**: check bellow answer

If you want `0.2677` formatted as `0.27` you should use `new DecimalFormat("0.00");` otherwise it will be `.27`

Comment: @Necroqubus You're confusing java.text.DecimalFormat (API 1) with android.icu.text.DecimalFormat (API 24). Please do proper research before posting wrong information everywhere.

Comment: Note that DecimalFormat is NOT threadsafe.

Answer (score 24):

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Use this code to get exact two decimal points.
Even if the value is 0.0 it will give u 0.00 as output.

Instead if you use:

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

It wont convert *0.2659* into *0.27*. You will get an answer like **.27**.

Comment: why this doesn't have more votes?! it is important information that should be added to the accepted answer

Comment: why its not converting my float value 98786545/10^6  to two decimal format. After converting it to two decimal i want to save it as a string.

Comment: @sports  Requires API level 24 hence pretty bad solution for projects with compatibility

Answer (score 16):

Try this: `String.format("%.2f", angle);`

Comment: Best answer for those with min API below 24! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
```