# Display as two Decimal

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a number to 2 decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779659/convert-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-java)

I need to display a decimal number up to two digits in Java.

For example:

```
Case1.   2.333 - 2.33
Case2.   3.4 -   3.40
```

I am able to do the first case. Can anybody help me how to do for the second case.

Comment: @RohitJain Probably just a typo in the question.

Comment: try `NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##");`

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to print a double with two digits after the decimal point, use something like this:

```
double value = 200.3456;
System.out.printf("Value: %.2f", value);
```

If you want to have the result in a String instead of being printed to the console, use String.format() with the same arguments:

```
String result = String.format("%.2f", value);
```

Or use class DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");
System.out.println("Value: " + df.format(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f%n", 2.333, 3.4);
```

prints

```
2.33 3.40
```